# Where are the API docs for SymmetricSecurityKey class?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm looking for the API docs for the class

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey

which is part of the [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/5.1.2) nuget package.

The [.Net API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=Micirosoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey) does not return any results.

Where else should I look?

Comment: Came across your question as i was facing the same issue. But i've resolved... SymmetricSecurity class can be imported by adding this  `using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;`